# What are the connection parameters or properties used for Https connection in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am doing a small app where it connects to my server and communicates over https. In blackberry 5.0 and above it works fine but in BB 4.5 it shows me the popup for certificate for each request i makes. Please help me in that. I just don't want to get the popup every time.

any parameter or jad properties that i can make use.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your SSL certificate was added to BB sometime after the 4.5 OS was released.

If you intend this app to go into production you could replace it with a cert that is known by OS4.5 phones, most Verisign certs will work.

I don't think there is a way to programmatically trust a new certificate authority.

If you can't replace the server's cert, perhaps you could present an explanation early as to why the cert should be trusted...